# NameError: name 'elmo' is not defined tensorflow hub python

Tags: python, tensorflow, bots

I am using `tensorflow==1.15.5`.

And I am loading pretrained model like this

```
# loading pre trained model to extract elmo vectors
# this is required to load custom model    
elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)
class DeepLearningBot:

    dirName = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    stopwords = ['i',  'am', 'a',
                 'to', 'is', 'do', 'in', 'of']
    labelModelPath = os.path.join(dirName, "config/labels_mapping.pkl")
    modelPath = os.path.join(dirName,"models/elmo-model-bilstm2.h5")

    def init():
        Logger.log("Using tensorflow : " + tf.__version__)
        DeepLearningBot.modelBlstm = tf.keras.models.load_model(DeepLearningBot.modelPath)
```

To load the custom model elmo variable is needed (inside model elmo variable is required)

I have intialized the variable `elmo` outside the class but when I load the model inside `init()` method  it says

```
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "c:\\env37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "c:\PERSONAL\projects\AdamAI\adam-chat-server\env37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 191, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "c:\env37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1081, in from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "c:\PERSONAL\projects\AdamAI\adam-chat-server\env37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1039, in process_node
    layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "c:\env37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 854, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\env37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 789, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "<ipython-input-45-e850aa69f190>", line 3, in ELMoEmbedding_bl
NameError: name 'elmo' is not defined
```

Now how can i solve this ?

and is there any other way to configure the pre trained model?

Answer (score 0):

Model was using the variable `elmo` and `tf`, so it was expecting these variables to be declared before loading the model.

There is other way to pass it while loading the model by using `custom_objects` property

```
DeepLearningBot.modelBlstm = tf.keras.models.load_model(DeepLearningBot.modelPath,
                                                                custom_objects={
                                                                    'elmo': hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=False),
                                                                    'tf': tf
                                                                })
```